# Variavel Indefinida / Callback em javascript AccountAddress

Tags: javascript, variáveis, callback

estou enfrentando um problema no meu projeto: resulmidamente é o seguinte:
Minha variavel local não está sendo definida mesmo estando definida. é problema de Callback, como posso resolver?

Explico melhor a situação mais abaixo.

no meu banco de dados está assim:
Endereco de email | ID Membro;

Eu preciso buscar o ID do membro pelo endereço de email que ele me fornecer.

Dentro da função getCont existe duas variaveis local, um obejeto e uma função, e dois log;

O ID member é uma variavel local da função getCont e recebe indefinido.
endereco é uma variavel local que representa o email informado pelo usuario.

o AccountAddress é o objeto com o nome dado para minha estrutura no banco de dados, a variavel endereço busca um valor do IDMembro;

ex: busca endereco de email teste@teste.com e retorna o  ID member e define a variavel IDMember que no exemplo deve ser 1; 1º membro cadastro.
e IDMember agora é definido;
Até aí tudo funciona.

agora vem o problema:
quando pego o IDMember que está no scopo local e faço console.log fora do objeto AccountAddress, ele automaticamente volta indefinido.

Eu entendi que tem a sicronia e callback... blz, como posso fazer callback do objeto AccountAddress já que, ele possui uma função e um retorno? segue o codigo a abaixo:

Muito Obrigado

```
HelloWorld.prototype.getCont = function(cb) { 

    var IDMember; 
    var endereco = window.web3.eth.accounts[0];

    document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML =  endereco;

    this.instance.AccountAddress(endereco, function (error, result) {      
        IDMember = result;   
       document.getElementById("IDAccount").innerHTML =  IDMember;   
       console.log(IDMember);
    }) 

    console.log(AccontAddress()); 
}
```

Comment: Vai ter que chamar uma Promise e usar o `await`. Edite a pergunta  e coloque o código `AccontAddress()` e aproveite e retire `var` de `var IDMember = result;`

Comment: `console.log(AccontAddress());` Retorna isso
ReferenceError: AccontAddress is not defined
mesmo usando o `return IDMember;  });`
Vou ver como uso promisses e wait muito obrigado pela dica

Comment: tenta `log(this.instance.AccountAddress)`, deve vir algo.

Comment: Sim, veio isso
`ƒ (){return!this._constant?this.sendTransaction.apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)):this.call.apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))}`

Comment: Então é uma função definida por você no seu *código fonte*  então coloque o código que usou para definir essa função na pergunta. Para poder entendermos o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Um detalhe: no console ele é array.no console vem assim `e {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array(1)}`
e ` IDMember = result; ` é 1. sem precisar fazer nem um tipo de tratamento de array.

Comment: Ferrou! Estou usando builder :(
como não sei usar o WEB3 js. e teria de criar um nó e instalar N programas. eu encontrei um site que faz isso. a unica coisa que eu fiz foi o banco de dados, e os codigos de front end do javascript e nem todos